# Why is this code considered O(N^6) in Big Oh notation?

Tags: c, for-loop, big-o, notation

I was just reading [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468257/big-o-notation-runtime) and this code intrigued me:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < i*j; k++)
        {
            pseudo_inner_count++;
            for(l = 0; l < 10; l++);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this can be O(N^6). Can someone break it down for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually it is:

- The i loop iterates O(N) times, so the value of i is O(N), so we can say O(I)=O(N).
- The j loop iterates O(I^2) = O(N^2) times (when considered on its own, without the outer loop).
- The k loop iterates O(I*J) = O(N*N^2) = O(N^3) times.
- The l loop just iterates 10 times so that is O(1).

The loops are nested so we have to multiply these together (do you understand why?).  The total is O(N)*O(N^2)*O(N^3) = O(N^6).

Comment: Ok, so the final result is achieved through a multiplication of the evaluations of each loop, and not through a sum (as @Pascal suggested). Can someone else confirm this?

Comment: Pascal did not really do the sum.  He multiplied n * n^2 * n^2 * n and got n^6.  It might look like a sum because the exponents add together but that's just how exponents work in math.

Comment: @karl: Well law of exponents say we add the exponents since the terms we're multiplying have the same base.  I don't see how you came to the conclusion that he's taking the sum of something.

Comment: @karlphillip: Think about it, it only makes sense to multiply. For example, if an inner loop performs some operation 5 times, and then an outer loop performs the inner loop 10 times, then the operation is performed 5*10=50 times. Big O notation is similar, except that you are multiplying functions. [Note: this is a useful but non-rigorous way of thinking about it!]

Answer (score 1):

It's

n for the first loop
n² for the second loop
n³ for the third loop

The inner loop is O(1)

The total is O(n⁶).

The reason the third loop is n³ is because when you think about it j reaches n² and i reaches n, so i*j reaches n³.

Answer (score -1):

I would say :

- n for the first loop
- n² for the second loop => total of n³
- n² for the third loop => total of n⁵
- yet another n-loop => total of n⁶

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see how the innermost loop can be O(n) when it executes in constant time, regardless of the value of n.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like O(N^5) to me

Comment: I downvoted.  The loop `for(l = 0; l < 10; l++);` is O(1), not O(N).

Comment: @karlphillip, @antiome, @bdares, the inner loop is `O(1)`. The whole thing is still `O(n^6)` because the third loop is n^3.